# Sending email in PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, email

I am trying to send email in PHP using AJAX in a simple contact form. I have the following codes for a simple form, PHP code for submit button and AJAX script.

When I am trying to send email it is not sending any email and always firing the AJAX error msg. I am not very well in AJAX integration with PHP.

Below is my code

```
 <form method="post" class="myform" action="">
       <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required><br>
       <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required><br>
       <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"> <span class="output_message"></span>
 </form>

 <?php
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

      // Set your email address where you want to receive emails. 
       $to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
       $subject = 'Contact Request From Website';
       $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n";
       $send_email = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

       echo ($send_email) ? 'success' : 'error';

  }?>

    <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.myform').on('submit',function(){

           // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
           $('.output_message').text('Loading...'); 

           var form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                method: form.attr('method'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(result){
            if (result == 'success'){
                $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');  
            } else {
                $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
            }
        }
    });

    // Prevents default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
    return false;   
  });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: is your URL parameter not empty?

Comment: only the error msg Error Sending email

Comment: in your $.ajax code, you should put url: /path/to/your/phpfile.php

Comment: but i have no external php file, only trying to put the code in same file isn't that possible?

Comment: I think you should still give the path to the current file. Now you are sending request to ""

Comment: or simply move your php code to email.php and set that in your ajax url as parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would move the php part to another file:

```
<form method="post" class="myform" action="">
       <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required><br>
       <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required><br>
       <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"> <span class="output_message"></span>
 </form>



    <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.myform').on('submit',function(){

           // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
           $('.output_message').text('Loading...'); 

           var form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                url: "email.php",
                method: form.attr('method'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(result){
            if (result == 'success'){
                $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');  
            } else {
                $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
            }
        }
    });

    // Prevents default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
    return false;   
  });
  });

</script>
```

And in another email.php

```
 <?php
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

      // Set your email address where you want to receive emails. 
       $to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
       $subject = 'Contact Request From Website';
       $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n";
       $send_email = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

       echo ($send_email) ? 'success' : 'error';

  }?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked when i moved my php to different file location and show the path in ajax url.But I am finding another problem though it is sending mail but it shows always the error msg not the success msg

Comment: @Mithu I'm not sure what the $send_email variable contains? what if you change the last line to echo ($send_email != false) ? 'success' : 'error';

Comment: when changing to ($send_email != false) ? 'success' : 'error'; it is not sending mail nor showing any msg

Comment: Hmm okay, sorry. Im not sure how the mail() function should respond. But it seams like it is responding either false or a hash - which will always be false in your if shorthand statement. See response section here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 0):

So, the top answer works, but as @Mithu said, for some reason it always says:
'Error Sending email!'
After 30 minutes of exploring the situation I understood that for some reason it returns from PHP not 'success' but '   success' with 2-4 spaces in front of the word 'success' or 'error'.
So, all you need is to exclude these spaces, for that we need to change 'succes' to 'this is success' and 'error' to 'this is error'(just to make spare letters in the front) and then we need to divide this string to words and to extract the last word. It will always be 'success' or 'error' regardless how much spaces the script will add or how much letters it will remove accidentally. And also you need to make another if else statement in the PHP to check FALSE instead of TRUE.

Also I've added a few lines which check if the fields are filled or not. And if they are not filled then you get a message 'Please fill in the forms.'.

So here how it looks and works for me:

**Importing jquery library** (you need to place it into the header):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML** (you need to put it there where you want to have the contact form):

```
<form method="post" class="myform" action="">
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br>
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
   <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"> <span class="output_message"></span>
</form>
```

**JS** (you need to put it in the footer):

```
<script>
               $(document).ready(function() {
               $('.myform').on('submit',function(){
    
               // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
               $('.output_message').text('Loading...'); 
    
               var form = $(this);
                    $.ajax({
                    // if it can't find email.php just chahge the url path to the full path, including your domain and all folders.
                    url: "email.php",
                    method: form.attr('method'),
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function(result){
                
                // THIS IS WHAT I HAVE ADDED TO REMOVE EXCESS SPACES
                let d = result.split(" ");
                let y = d.slice(-1)[0];
                // THIS IS WHAT I HAVE ADDED TO REMOVE EXCESS SPACES

                if (y == 'success'){
                    $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');  
                } 
                else if (y == 'miss'){
                     $('.output_message').text('Please fill in all the fields above.');
                }
                else {
                    $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
                }
            }
        });
    
        // Prevents default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
        return false;   
      });
      });
    
</script>
```

**email.php** (you need to create this file in the same folder where you have your index.php):

```
 <?php


 // here we check if all fields are filled.
 $required = array('name', 'email', 'message');
 $error = false;
 foreach($required as $field) {
   if (empty($_REQUEST[$field])) {
     $error = true;
   }
 }

 //if something is not filled(empty) and error is true
 if ($error) {
   echo 'this is miss';
 }
 // if everything is filled then we execute the mail function
 else {

    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $fullmessage = "Sender's name: ".$name."\n"."Message: \n".$message;

  // Set your email address where you want to receive emails.
   $to = 'contact@yourdomain.com';
   $subject = 'Message from YOUR E-MAIL.COM';
   $send_email = mail($to,$subject,$fullmessage,$email);


   if ($send_email == false) {
     echo 'this is error';
   } else {
     echo 'this is success';
   }
   }
   ?>
```

So,this code steadily works for me, but maybe it is not very proffessionaly made, because I am a begginer in JS and PHP.

Comment: Well done for clarifying the cause of the failure and also providing good code samples for other developers to follow.

Comment: @quinny, thank you. I have just updated it because I discovered that it adds not always 3 spaces in the front but sometimes 2 or 1 or nothing. So, now it has to be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You must be stop the default flow of that form by using `event.preventDefault();` and you can pass the form as multipart/formdata or form-data and check the `developer tools -> network -> fetch/xhr -> payload/ formdata`. then you create a seperate page in php and do the mail process in that page and change the form action link to that page

**In html**

```
<form method="post" class="myform" action="mail.php">
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br>
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
   <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"> <span class="output_message"></span>
</form>

<script>
         $(document).on('submit', '.myform', function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
           // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
           $('.output_message').text('Loading...'); 

           var form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                method: form.attr('method'),
                data: new FormData($(".myform")[0]),
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(result){
            if (result.status == 'success'){
                $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');  
            } else {
                $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**In php - mail.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

      // Set your email address where you want to receive emails. 
       $to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
       $subject = 'Contact Request From Website';
       $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n";
       $send_email = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
       if($send_email)
        {
          $response = ['status' => 'success'];
        }
        else
        {
          $response = ['status' => 'error'];
        }
       echo json_encode($response);    
  }
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The other answers, which are months older than yours, already mention that the form submission should be prevented (by returning false from that event handling method)

Comment: Sorry. I'm not checked that and i removed it